# duda sobre agregar elementos a un string

Tags: python, string

Tengo una duda sobre este ejercicio
Escribir una función que sanitiza una cadena. El método de sanitización es el siguiente:
a. Todas las letras con tilde se cambian por la misma letra sin tilde.

b. Símbolos de pregunta y de exclamación se reemplazan por guiones (“-“)

c. Los espacios se reemplazan por guiones bajos (“_")

d. La "ñ" se reemplaza por la “n"

e. Cualquier otro símbolo (que no sean letras) se remueve.

la condición que no se como cumplir es la e

hasta ahora mi código es este:

```
def sanitizarcadena(string):
    cadenavacia=""
    cadenaelementos="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZñ áéíóú?!¡"
    for elem in string:
        if elem in cadenaelementos  and elem=="á":
            elem="a"
        else:
            if elem in cadenaelementos and elem=="é":
                elem="e"
            else:
                if elem in cadenaelementos and elem=="í":
                    elem="i"
                else:
                    if elem in cadenaelementos and elem=="ó":
                        elem="o"
                    else:
                        if elem in cadenaelementos and elem=="u":
                            elem="u"
                        else:
                            if elem in cadenaelementos and elem=="?":
                                elem="-"
                            else:
                                if elem in cadenaelementos and elem=="!":
                                    elem="-"
                                else:
                                    if elem in cadenaelementos and elem=="¡":
                                        elem="-"
                                    else:
                                        if elem in cadenaelementos and elem==" ":
                                            elem="_"
                                        else:
                                            if elem in cadenaelementos and elem =="ñ":
                                                elem="n"
                                                if elem in cadenaelementos:
                                                    cadenavacia=cadenavacia+elem
        cadenavacia+=elem
    return cadenavacia
print(sanitizarcadena("áéíóó? ñ****"))
```

Comment: se me ocurre que podría crear una nueva cadena con todos los símbolos del teclado, pero creo que es una opción muy larga y mi idea es buscar una forma de optimizarla.

Comment: Pareciera que el ejercicio le dice "simbolo" a todo lo que no sea una letra. Podrias usar eso para guiarte. Por cierto, te aconsejo usar elif para evitar esos if-else anidados.

Answer (score 1):

Hola se me ocurre trabajarlo de esta forma usa un diccionario con las letras o caracteres que desees cambiar luego recorres y validas si existe o no si no esta dentro del dicionarios lo omites y listo el código quedaria algo asi.

```
def sanitizarcadena(string):
cadenavacia=""
cadenaelementos="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZñ áéíóú?!¡"

dic_caracteres = {
    "á": "a",
    "é": "e",
    "í": "i",
    "ó": "o",
    "ú": "u",
    "?": "-",
    "!": "-",
    "ñ": "n",
    " ": "_"
}
for elem in string:
    if elem in cadenaelementos:
        if elem in dic_caracteres:
          elem_cambiado=elem.replace(elem,dic_caracteres[elem])
          cadenavacia = cadenavacia + elem_cambiado
        cadenavacia = cadenavacia + ""
return cadenavacia
```

print(sanitizarcadena("áéíóó? ñ****"))

como Resultado la da lo siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]